# Separate seeds in PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, random-seed

How do I create a separate seed for some test inside one test class?
PHPUnit documentation includes this example

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPUnit/Extensions/Database/TestCase.php';

class DatabaseTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase
{
    protected function getConnection()
    {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb', 'root', '');
        return $this->createDefaultDBConnection($pdo, 'testdb');
    }

    protected function getDataSet()
    {
        return $this->createFlatXMLDataSet(dirname(__FILE__).'/_files/bank-account-seed.xml');
    }
}
?>
```

But in this example I have one seed for all the tests inside my class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the answer.
One possible way to do it is to use setDataSet method.

Example:

```
$newSet =   $this->createFlatXmlDataSet(dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/_files/members.xml');        
$this->getDatabaseTester()->setDataSet($newSet);
$this->getDatabaseTester()->onSetUp();
```

If you put it in your test function, it will reset default seed to any other, that you need.